# Integration issue with PyObjC and TKinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyobjc

The following simple code:

```
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
import AppKit
import Tkinter

class App(AppKit.NSApplication):

    def finishLaunching(self):
        self.root=Tkinter.Tk()

_=App.sharedApplication()
AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

yields the following exception:  `Python[23717:d07] -[App _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105d05340`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can mix Tkinter and Cocoa toolkits so interchangeably. `self.root` is an attribute on the class `App`, which inherits from `AppKit.NSApplication`. My guess is that the `Tk()` call returns a pointer that is then passed to the Cocoa frameworks, but points to a Tk data structure that it can't understand. Also, both Tkinter and PyObjC need their own eventloop; I'm not sure if you can even mix the two (though I've never tried).

My recommendation would be to use one UI toolkit or the other, but not both.